# in linux, how to protect files from being erased/modified?

Tags: linux, chmod

That might be a basic question, but I have a bunch of files that look like

```
top_secret_001
top_secret_002
etc
```

I would like to be sure that they are **not erased nor modified** by anyone. They should be readable though.

How can I do that in linux?

Thanks!

Comment: Plain and simple: You can not. root can do anything.

Comment: chmod 744 will be rwx by owner read by all others. but as noted root can delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `chown` the file to be owned by root, and then `chmod` it to have 0644 permissions.

Anybody with sudo/root access can write to or delete the file, so beware!

Another thing to note, if a user has write permissions to the directory the file is in, they may delete the file. Even if the file is owned by root with read only permissions.

Comment: thanks! what would be the exact commands then? sorry i am a linux noob

Comment: `sudo chown root:root super_secret` and then `sudo chmod 0644 super_secret` if you are logged in as root, just do the commands sans sudo.

Comment: Do you need to take write access away from the directory so that the file can't be deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the permissions and owner to root is as much as you can do... here is how [File security](http://tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_03_04.html)